# GoPro Fusion extended recording?

Tags: video-recording, 360video

### The Goal

I am looking at purchasing a [GoPro Fusion](https://shop.gopro.com/cameras/fusion/CHDHZ-103.html) in order to record a group of people gaming. The games will last for between 3 and 6 hours. I'm looking at the fusion because of how very unobtrusive it can feel relative to something like a multi-cam setup.

### The Question

Is it possible to create a setup for the GoPro Fusion or a competitor that will record for that kind of duration?

### Additional Notes

We will be in my home. I will therefore have access to pretty much anything I can afford: wall power, computers, wifi control, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very straightforward to set up, yes. Because you can fill up SD cards very quickly with the resolutions these are capable of, you could run one at 1080p for longer duration, but that's still not going to stretch to 6 hours.

For that length of game you will want to have it connected via USB to a PC of some kind recording the video feed directly to disk, and providing power.

Relatively simple - and in fact using the default software that comes with the GoPro Fusion, you can pretty much do that out of the box.

As the Fusion has voice commands, that can also make for a very unobtrusive recording station.

Comment: OMG squee! Thanks! I felt like that sort of feature should be possible, but after reading waaaay too much documentation I still hadn't found that feature listed. Thanks!

Comment: Initially when I was looking at GoPros for long recording sessions, I went down the route of low resolution, and then low frame rate (which potentially is something you could look at, depending on the kind of game), but connecting to a PC and using it to record solves your data capacity issue.